# SQL select rows and group as array items

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

My project contains of books (products) which were written by one or more authors.

The following database tables are available:

- Table "products"; columns "id", "title", etc.
- Table "authors"; columns "id", "name", "email" etc.
- Relation Table "products_auhtors"; columns "id", "product_id", "author_id"

Now I want to query all products and the result should include the related authors as well.

```
$products = $this->db( 'products' )
        ->join( 'products_authors', 'products.id', '=', 'products_authors.product_id' )
        ->join( 'authors', 'authors.id', '=', 'products_authors.author_id' )
        ->select(
            'products.*',
            'authors.*'
        )
        ->get();
```

**Problem**: I would like to have all authors (due to the fact that a product can have more than 1) grouped as arrays.

So in fact the results should look like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "title of the book"
        authors: [
            {
                id: 11,
                name: "name of author 1",
                email: "author1@email.com"
            },
            {
                id: 22,
                name: "name of author 2",
                email: "author2@email.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "title of the book2"
        authors: [
            {
                id: 11,
                name: "name of author 1",
                email: "author1@email.com"
            },
            {
                id: 22,
                name: "name of author 2",
                email: "author2@email.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm using [Laravel's query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) but of course I can make use of raw SQL too.

Any tip how I can get closer to my goal?

Comment: Do you have laravel models setup as well? if so relations can be used instead of manual queries.

Comment: No I'm not using models

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest it to not base on raw database relations, but rather on models.

You should have something like:

```
public function authors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Namespace\Author');
}
```

And then simply use

```
$products = Products::with('authors')->get();
```

---

Please also note that when you do a select like `->select('products.*','authors.*')`, then your products.id will be overwritten with authors.id, as it will be mapped to the results ['id'] key - it's a common mistake with queries in Laravel.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question because I'm using a pivot table which holds the product_id and author_id. By using "hasMany" as you suggested, a search inside the "authors" table will be done which is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\AuthorsModel', 'products_authors',
            'product_id', 'author_id');
```